# Error installing Sitecore PowerShell: "An entry with the same key already exists"

Tags: powershell-extensions, installation

I am trying to install `Sitecore PowerShell 6.4` version in our `Sitecore 9.0.2` from the GitHub repository (**https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/discussions/categories/general**), but I am encountering an error that says "An entry with the same key already exists." Here's the full error message:

**System.ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.**

```
An entry with the same key already exists. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.
```

I am not sure what is causing this error or how to fix it. Can anyone provide some guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you find something in logs like any particular item is creating the issue while installing the package?